# Correct way to fill un-needed callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider this code snippet:

```
transaction.executeSql(  
'SELECT * FROM pv_master;', [],  
    function(transaction, result) {  
        if(result.rows.length == 0) {  
        jQT.goTo("#register", 'slideup');  
        }  
    }, errorHandler  
);
```

This example is a little different to the question title as the square brackets should be filled with some value.

Imagine I didn't want a success callback but did want a failure callback, which comes second in this instance.

What would be the correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can simply put null, since [the algorithm](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#dom-sqltransaction-executesql) checks for this.  I wrote a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WcV6Y/7/) a while back that does this.  If the function didn't check, you would pass an empty function:

```
function(){}
```

Note that you wouldn't need to worry about the parameter count, since it's okay to call a JS function with too many parameters.